# Runtime Error Can't resolve all parameters for GoogleMap: (?, ?)

Tags: angular, cordova, google-maps, ionic3

i am trying to get an basic map to be loaded on my templet. I just followed this instruction https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/ to get my map works.

But i am getting error like above question.

here is my code

```
// Load map only after view is initialized
ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.loadMap();
}

loadMap() {
 // make sure to create following structure in your view.html file
 // and add a height (for example 100%) to it, else the map won't be visible
 // <ion-content>
 //  <div #map id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>
 // </ion-content>

 // create a new map by passing HTMLElement
 let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');

 let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element);

 // listen to MAP_READY event
 // You must wait for this event to fire before adding something to the map or modifying it in anyway
 map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(
   () => {
     console.log('Map is ready!');
     // Now you can add elements to the map like the marker
   }
 );

 // create LatLng object
 let ionic: LatLng = new LatLng(43.0741904,-89.3809802);

 // create CameraPosition
 let position: CameraPosition = {
   target: ionic,
   zoom: 18,
   tilt: 30
 };

 // move the map's camera to position
 map.moveCamera(position);

 }

}
```

> i am getting blank screen i am not able to print console.log in my app.compontent.ts file

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I changed my app.module.ts file

```
import {GoogleMaps,GoogleMap} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    GoogleMaps,
    GoogleMap
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
```

To this

```
import {GoogleMaps} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    GoogleMaps
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
```

Just removing the googleMap from my provider and imports i got it worked

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks

Comment: @Mohan Gopi its not worked for me sir after change above line?