# Ionic Google MAP API Error

Tags: api, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

Im used `IONIC-3` and  Try to add `Google MAP API` for My university project
Im Already follow this instruction  [Google MAP API](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/) ,same issue is mentioned here also [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309445/runtime-error-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-googlemap) but not work for me

**My error**

> Can't resolve all parameters for GoogleMap: (?, ?). at syntaxError

**app.module.ts**

```
import {GoogleMaps,GoogleMap} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
@NgModule({

  providers: [
    GoogleMaps,
    GoogleMap,]
```

**addproject.html**

```
<div class="map">
<div #map style="height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

**addproject.ts**

```
import { Componen } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,ViewController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
     import {
     GoogleMaps,
     GoogleMap,
     GoogleMapsEvent,
     GoogleMapOptions,
     CameraPosition,
     MarkerOptions,
     Marker
    } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';


        @IonicPage()
        @Component({
          selector: 'page-addproject',
          templateUrl: 'addproject.html',
        })
        export class AddprojectPage {
          @ViewChild('map')
          private mapElement:ElementRef;
          private map:GoogleMap;
          private location:LatLng;
      ionViewDidLoad() {
       this.loadMap();
   }
      map: GoogleMap;
      constructor(private googleMaps: GoogleMaps) { }
     loadMap() {

        let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
          camera: {
            target: {
              lat: 43.0741904,
              lng: -89.3809802
            },
            zoom: 18,
            tilt: 30
          }
        };

        this.map = this.googleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);

        // Wait the MAP_READY before using any methods.
        this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('Map is ready!');

            // Now you can use all methods safely.
            this.map.addMarker({
                title: 'Ionic',
                icon: 'blue',
                animation: 'DROP',
                position: {
                  lat: 43.0741904,
                  lng: -89.3809802
                }
              })
              .then(marker => {
                marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
                  .subscribe(() => {
                    alert('clicked');
                  });
              });

          });
      }
    }
```

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for GoogleMap: (?, ?).
>       at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:78533:34)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:93614:35)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:93449:26)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:93429:21)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:93789:40)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:93700:49
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:93660:19)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:93228:50)
>       at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:111609:87)

Comment: Try to remove GoogleMap from import and providers in app.module.ts

Comment: @MarioPadilla its work but google map not displayed

Comment: It's because you are missing the reference (id) to 'map_canvas' in your addproject.html

You need to add something like '<div id="map_canvas"></div>' in your addproject.html